# Stop jquery smooth scrolling 300px above link-target

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, smooth-scrolling

I've got a question concerning the jquery smooth scrolling. I read that I can move the section I link to by giving a minus-value to this lines:

```
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
  }, 800, function(){
```

https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_eff_animate_smoothscroll -> this example works as expected - when clicking on the link, the smooth scrolling ends at the top of the  blue box.

Please click on the link to the image: [Default behavior shown in the example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hu5QQ.jpg)

When trying to set the point a bit higher over the blue box, I just added (as shown in a lot of posts / tutorials using this javascript example) the "- 300" pixel value behind it.

The lines now look like this:

```
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top -300
  }, 800, function(){
```

Please click on the link to the image: [Desired behavior which i tried by adding "-300"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2H9I.jpg)

Result here:
https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GFC6NW9RONPX

The scrolling goes down the right way, it stops 300px above the blue box (as wanted) for just a milisecond (not wanted), then it swtiches down to the anchor in the blue box as in example 1 (not wanted).

Please click on the link to the image: [Actual behavior not desired](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A43n7.jpg)

I don't know why, and I also had problems to search for the problem with proper words (so my search did not succeed). Can anybody give me a little hint, so my smooth scrolling stops 300px above the link target?

Thanks and best in advance!

Comment: what do you want to achieve here?

Comment: Don't want to be disrespectful, but: Have you read the question?

Comment: yes, but it not understandable. That's why I have asked. If the question would be clear you might get answers already.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback - I've added images to clarify what I want to achieve. In a nutshell - this is what I want: https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2H9I.jpg.

What happens right now - this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/A43n7.jpg.

My wish: Stop the smooth scrolling 300px above the target-div.